# Is this method of copying a string faster than copying each char individually?

Tags: c, string, copy, unsafe

Is this method of copying a string faster than copying each char individually? The idea of this code is that it could (but I am not sure if it is so) be faster to copy 8 bytes at once instead of a single byte. It is very un-safe but it seems to work somehow. Or it's just a bad idea?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void* copy_string(char s[])
{
    int len=strlen(s);
    int i=0;

    double *p=(double*)s;
    double *copy=(double*)malloc(len+1);

    while(i-len>8)
    {
         *copy=*(p++);
         copy++;
         i+=8;
    }
    char *p2=(char*)p;
    char *c=(char*)copy;
    while(i<len)
    {
         *c=*(p2++);
         c++;
         i++;
    }
    *c='\0';
    return copy;
}

int main()
{
    char s[]="GOODBYE SAFE WORLD!";
    char *c=copy_string(s);
    printf("%s",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just memcpy it? Trying to loop unroll a byte by byte copy seems kinda pointless; though for giggles you could look up Duffs Device...

Comment: It is just curiosity.

Comment: Why not benchmarking it?

Comment: It may or may not be faster, but it would definitely violate strict aliasing and is therefore likely to fail, especially in this example on architectures that place alignment restrictions on `double` variables.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: you are right. i-len does nothing

Comment: @AndrewHenle, this has nothing to do with strict aliasing. Assuming that the condition of the first `while` loop is fixed, the rules for pointer conversions are violated: *A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is
undefined.* On many architectures this will simply result in a "bus error".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricks like that *may* be faster under some circumstances on some architectures. Trust your provider of your C library to know about these tricks if they apply.

In your case, your code is simply wrong. Assuming that the condition of the first while loop is fixed, the rules for pointer conversions are violated:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly
>   aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

On many architectures this will simply result in a "bus error".

To see how these kind of tricks work, check out the sources of your favorite C library and look for their implementation of `memcpy` and `memmove`.

Comment: I guess it is just better to stay out of trouble.

Comment: @Cosmin Butnaru No, push the limits.  Better than being [another brick in the wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Another_Brick_in_the_Wall).

Comment: I made it work properly. It is slower than memcpy. It is still a good trick for Obfuscated C contest.